# Faking a closure's function name

Tags: php, closures

Leaving out a long story, I have a scenario like this:

```
class Foo {

  function doSomething() {
    print "I was just called from " . debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];
  }

  function triggerDoSomething()
  {
    // This outputs "I was just called from triggerDoSomething".  
    // This output makes me happy.
    $this->doSomething();
  }

  function __call($method, $args)
  {
    // This way outputs "I was just called from __call"
    // I need it to be "I was just called from " . $method
    $this->doSomething();

    // This way outputs "I was just called from {closure}"
    // Also not what I need.
    $c = function() { $this->doSomething() };
    $c();

    // This causes an infinite loop
    $this->$method = function() { $this->doSomething() };
    $this->$method();
  }
}
```

In the case that I call $foo->randomFunction(), I need the the output to read "I was just called from randomFunction"

Is there a way to name a closure or approach this problem differently?

Note: I cannot change the doSomething function.  It is a sample of third-party code I'm calling that considers the function name of who called it in order to do something.

Comment: @Anthony, if using `eval()` is fine with you, you can check my updated answer.

Comment: Why is the backtrace so important? What's the actual problem you're dealing with?

Comment: I think it'd take a long time to explain properly because there are many layers of special circumstances.  But in a nutshell, I'm using Laravel Eloquent ORM (mixed with Neo4j and NeoEloquent) and I'm trying to dynamically declare relationship methods via __call() in a parent class, but Laravel uses the method name itself as part of its logic.  It's nothing I can change.  Thus I've simplified the whole scenario to the core issue, above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the name to `doSomething()` like

```
$this->doSomething($method);
```

or with closure like

```
$c = function($func_name) { $this->doSomething($func_name); };
$c($method);
```

and in `doSomething` you can use that parameter.

```
function doSomething($method) {
    print "I was just called from " . $method;
}
```

Comment: I think op said he couldn't modify doSomething

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I think that was after i posted this.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of without changing anything in doSomething() is using `eval()`

```
function __call($method, $args)
{
    eval("
         function {$method}(\$self) {
              \$self->doSomething();
         }

         {$method}(\$this);
    ");
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over doSomething(), unfortunately.  My class just simplifies the whole scenario.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I'll give it a try!